# How to fix GRUB menu not showing until I press Esc?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

After a dual-boot Windows 10/Ubuntu 18.04 installation, it looked like the PC was booting straight to Ubuntu, without showing the GRUB menu, after a short pause. I had already run Boot Repair under Ubuntu and checked bcdedit under Windows.

It turned out, during boot I had to hit the Esc key when the screen turned Ubuntu-purple, in order to display the GRUB menu and be allowed to choose the OS to boot. Not pressing Esc, after a time-out, the PC would boot to the default (Ubuntu).

I don't want to have to hit Esc every time during boot: how can I have the boot process show the GRUB menu right away, with no need for me to hit Esc?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't comment @Fanta, but after turning off **GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE** setting I got another error, something about "Couldn't find hwmatch module".

I fixed it not by turning off the **GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE** setting, but setting it from **hidden** to **menu**

See more about that setting [here in the GRUB manual on gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Simple-configuration.html).

Answer (score 0):

- Install and run Grub Customizer
- From the **General Settings** tab, click on **advanced settings**
- In the window that pops up, disable **GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE** (as per screenshot below)
- Close, save and exit
- Reboot to test

[image: Grub Customizer settings dialog]